# What acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID means and how should I fix it?

Tags: acpi

I found this in my logs:

```
kernel: acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
kernel: acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
```

What does it mean and how should I fix it?

```bsh
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Comment: It may be just a harmless warning: [https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201885#c10](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201885#c10)